# Java Spring Boot v2.6.4 - circular reference issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I get the following error whilst trying to run the application. Any help is appreciated.

"*Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bCryptEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?*"

2 related files for the issue are as follows:

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    private AuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfig(AuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler, JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil) {
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userServiceImpl)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new AuthenticationFilter(userServiceImpl, jwtTokenUtil);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/auth/*",
                        "/token/*",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/",
                        "/uploads/**",
                        "favicon.ico"
                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptEncoder; // Fails when injected by the constructor.

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user.
     * @param createUserDto
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public User save(CreateUserDto createUserDto) {
        User newUser = new User();

        newUser.setEmail(createUserDto.getEmail());
        newUser.setFullName(createUserDto.getFullName());
        newUser.setPassword(bCryptEncoder.encode(createUserDto.getPassword()));
        newUser.setConfirmed(createUserDto.isConfirmed());
        newUser.setEnabled(createUserDto.isEnabled());
        newUser.setRole(createUserDto.getRole());

        return userRepository.save(newUser);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        userRepository.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(list::add);
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (optionalUser.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(USER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE);
        }

        return optionalUser.get();
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(String id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(id);

        if (optionalUser.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(USER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE);
        }

        return optionalUser.get();
    }

    @Override
    public User update(String id, UpdateUserDto updateUserDto) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user = findById(id);

        if (updateUserDto.getFullName() != null) {
            user.setFullName(updateUserDto.getFullName());
        }

        if (updateUserDto.getEmail() != null) {
            user.setEmail(updateUserDto.getEmail());
        }

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User updatePassword(String id, UpdatePasswordDto updatePasswordDto) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user = findById(id);

        if (bCryptEncoder.matches(updatePasswordDto.getCurrentPassword(), user.getPassword())) {
            user.setPassword(bCryptEncoder.encode(updatePasswordDto.getNewPassword()));
            return userRepository.save(user);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePassword(String id, String newPassword) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user = findById(id);
        user.setPassword(bCryptEncoder.encode(newPassword));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void confirm(String id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user = findById(id);
        user.setConfirmed(true);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail(username);

        if(userOptional.isEmpty()){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }

        User user = userOptional.get();

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, user.isConfirmed(), getAuthority(user)
        );
    }

    private Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthority(User user) {
        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getName()));

        user.allPermissions().forEach(permission -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getName())));

        return authorities;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place the bean factory method for the encoder in a separate configuration class or you can leave it where it is and make the bean factory method static:

```
@Bean
public static BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

This make it clear to Spring that the encoder does not depend on anything injected into the class instance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a class annotated with @Configuration will be subjected to executed initially in a Spring application. As we can see you have created a lot of beans that has to be autowired in multiple other classes which will be created eventually probably the classes annotated with service, controller and all.

Now in the `WebSecurityConfig` there is an autowiring for `UserServiceImpl`
for which the bean hasn't created yet it will be created after the configuration class is done. And the `UserServiceImpl` also requires `BCryptPasswordEncoder` So this appears like a dead lock each of them is dependent on one another. This is what I could decipher.

Also autowiring should be done with Interface as type.

```
@Autowired
private UserService userServiceImpl;
```

I think moving the password encoder bean creation to another config class might help to solve this situation.

Comment: Not sure what needs to change in the code to rectify this issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating a new configuration class as follows;

```
@Configuration
public class PasswordSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I used this class in the WebSecurityConfig as follows;

```
@Autowired
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userServiceImpl)
            .passwordEncoder(new PasswordSecurityConfig().bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

I can now run the app without any issues.

Comment: Curious what if we autowire the bycryptPasswordEncoder inside the WebSecurityConfig since the other PasswordSecurityConfig would have created the instance to inject.